# Show each sheet in a continuous loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which shows each worksheet in a workbook on a continuous loop, going to the next page every 5 seconds. I have a graph on each worksheet that needs to be shown on a continuous loop.

Answer (score 0):

Win 32:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub ShowWs()
Dim ws
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Sleep (1000)
Next ws
End Sub
```